# Getting issue while installing Windows Phone SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, hyper-v

I am new to wp development while installing. windows mobile sdk i am getting an error "This computer does not support windows phone emulator which requires the 64 bit edition of windows 8.1 pro and a computer that supports Hiper-V" as shown in the below screen shot....

I am using windows 8.1 pro 64 bit operating system and dual core second generation processor and 4 gb ram.

[image]

Comment: Dual core second generation sounds quite old in my ears. Maybe it has no Hyper-V support?

Comment: I found that if you want to run your Windows Phone 8.1 App in an emulator, there are requirements to be met before you can use the emulator. Here are the findings and time savers :

http://goo.gl/lUmJQM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows phone emulator installation should requires SLAT support for the machine

See the requirements for WP 8
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx

Check whether your system has SLAT support using the below software

http://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/

If your machine is SLAT enabled make sure the[image] Hyper-V settings in "Windows Features" as below:

Comment: after running this it is showing "Your machine does not have hardware virtualization capability. So, your machine is not SLAT capable."

Comment: So you will not be able to install Windows Phone Emulator on your device as SLAT support is mandatory for installation. You can test your application by deploying it on Windows Phone 8 Device if you are having a developer account with you.

Comment: How much does a developer account costs

Comment: You can do development without a paid account. You're only allowed one test device.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Can you share any link for free development on one test device?

Comment: Until you publish, you don't need an account. I don't have a paid developer account, but still do test development with a physical Windows Phone. At some point, VS will indicate what you need to do. I don't remember it being difficult (sorry, it's been 6 months since I needed to do it).

Comment: @WiredPrairie is Nokia Lumia 520 is enough as test device.

Comment: Yes.  It represents the lowest end device, which means if your app runs well on that, it should be fine on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

It works only on the processor that has HYPER-V(Virtualization). All the intel i-series supports virtualization.